# Using Maps to store data in JDBC postgresql

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I'm trying to create a table called TOPPINGS_IN_STOCK and insert datas into it, but I've come across with an error. What's wrong?

```
package insertToDataBase;    
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Toppings {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        Map<String, Integer> toppings = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        toppings.put("cheese", 1);
        toppings.put("sausage", 2);
        toppings.put("pepper", 3);

        Map<Integer, String> topSizeAndQty = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        topSizeAndQty.put(3, "small");
        topSizeAndQty.put(4, "medium");
        topSizeAndQty.put(2, "large");

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/stock", "capfer", "123456");
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE TOPPINGS_IN_STOCK " + "(ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,"
                    + " TOPPING_NAME  TEXT    NOT NULL, " + " TOPPING_SIZE TEXT  NOT NULL,"
                    + "TOPPING_QTY INT NOT NULL)";
            st.executeUpdate(sql);

            String query = "INSERT INTO TOPPINGS_IN_STOCK(id, topping_name,topping_size,topping_qty)"
                    + " VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

            pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
            int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry1 : toppings.entrySet()) {
                for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry2 : topSizeAndQty.entrySet()) {

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        for (int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns + 1; i++) {

                            pst.setInt(1, entry1.getValue());
                            pst.setString(2, entry1.getKey());
                            pst.setString(3, entry2.getValue());
                            pst.setInt(4, entry2.getKey());
                            pst.addBatch();
                            // pst.executeUpdate();
                            pst.setInt(1, entry1.getValue());
                            pst.setString(2, entry1.getKey());
                            pst.setString(3, entry2.getValue());
                            pst.setInt(4, entry2.getKey());
                            pst.addBatch();
                            // pst.executeUpdate();
                            pst.setInt(1, entry1.getValue());
                            pst.setString(2, entry1.getKey());
                            pst.setString(3, entry2.getValue());
                            pst.setInt(4, entry2.getKey());
                            pst.addBatch();
                            // pst.executeUpdate();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            pst.executeBatch();
            con.commit();
            System.out.println("Topping were successfully added to stock.");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Toppings.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } finally {

            try {

                if (pst != null) {
                    pst.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Toppings.class.getName());
                lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The error:

```
 Opened database successfully
апр 08, 2016 1:50:16 AM insertToDataBase.Toppings main
SEVERE:   Not Specified value for the parameter 1.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:  Not Specified value for the parameter 1.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.checkAllParametersSet(SimpleParameterList.java:225)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:190)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:161)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
    at insertToDataBase.Toppings.main(Toppings.java:48)
```

Comment: The error I got is: Not Specified value for the parameter 1.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-insert-records.htm

Change line 44 to ...

```
rs = pst.executeUpdate(query); but... it's not gonna work.
```

You are basically trying to retrieve an update from an insert statement.

```
rs = pst.exectuteQuery(query);  <--- this is not right
rs = pst.executeUpdate(query);  <---- rs is an integer of number of rows changed
```

You can retrieve result sets from executeQuery() only. Select statements.

executeUpdate() "this method returns an integer indicating the number of rows that were updated"

```
Insert statement > Then use > executeUpdate() - Returns an integer of rows changed
Select statement > Then use > executeQuery() - Returns a Result Set
```

Comment: I'm using eclipse. I've tried the commands and they're working fine. But here is not working!!! The line 44 is this one: rs = pst.executeQuery();

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. Your code is good, just work on the Sql statements. String query = "INSERT INTO TOPPINGS_IN_STOCK(id, topping_name,topping_size,topping_qty)"
                    + " VALUES(?,?,?,?)";  <---this one is the culprit

Comment: I've changed the code and I've got this error: wrong value for a number of "?"

Comment: New answer posted, let me know if it helps.

Comment: I'm so ggreatfull that you're trying to help. I do not understand the way you declared this statement: private preparedstatement pst; I've tried, but I got   some roor like this: Illegal modifier for the variable pst; only final is permitted

Comment: I've changed the code as you suggested, but I'm having the same error as before: Not Specified value for the parameter 1.

Comment: I just noticed you used executeQuery instead of executeUpdate, this should make a difference.

Comment: Jack, I'm still getting the same error: No value specified for parameter 1. Is threre any other way to fix this problem? Is there any suggestion of how to store data in jdbc using Collections?

Comment: I know and it's not going to work. I explain why in the answer. :)